# Is it good idea to inject services into EntityRepository?

Tags: php, orm, architecture

I'm working on my own ORM with Entity and EntityRepository classes

In any ORM i explored injecting any services into Entities is realy bad idea. But there's a question: is it good idea to inject service into Repository?

There's abstract example:

```
//$user is object of Entity class in ORM
//we need to get actual valid entities here
$relatedEntities = $user->getRelatedEntities();
//where getRelatedEntities() calls method of RelatedEntityRepository

RelatedEntityRepository {
    private $injectedService;

    public function getByUserId($userId){
        if(!$this->injectedService->hasValidUserData($userId)){
            $this->injectedService->doSomething($userId);
        }
        return $this->getFromDbByUserId($userId)
    }
    private function getFromDbByUserId($userId){
        //returns data from DB
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it's not a good idea.

Comment: No, never do that. I would try to implement a service layer which orchestrates other layers such as data (repository), cache, filter, validation etc. Your repository should be an hard dependency of your service, usually via constructor signature. Also, accessing to any kind of repository from inside the entity is also not good.